# React Native responding to child press events

Tags: javascript, react-native, events

I am looking for a solution that allows me to respond, from a parent component, to all child's press events (including childs nested in other components). In particular, I am interested in the press release events (such as onPressOut for TouchableOpacity and alike).

I don't want to interrupt child's response to that event, I only want to react further to that event to perform some other task. For this reason, I cannot use the capture phase on a parent component, because it will stop propagating the event further in the chain.

I also don't want to manually add press responding functionality to each child of the parent, because there would be many childs and it becomes a tedious task, especially in refactoring or reimplementation.

A parent TouchableOpacity component allows me, during the Bubbling event phase, to capture all press events when no child responds to them. But if a child responds to them, the event does not propagate further up in the chain, thus, it will never reach the parent TouchableOpacity.

In code:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPressOut={ this.doSomethingInParentWhenAChildIsPressed >
    <TouchableOpacity onPressOut={()=>{
        /* doing something in child, parent should react in addition to this */
    } />
    <View>
        <TouchableOpacity onPressOut={()=>{
            /* doing something in nested child, parent should react in addition to this */
        } />
    </View>
    <View>
        <Text>When this text is pressed, the parent TouchableOpacity responds</Text>
        <View>
            <TouchableOpacity onPressOut={()=>{
                /* doing something in other nested child, parent should react in addition to this */
            } />
        </View>
        <View>
            <Text>The parent TouchableOpacity also responds on this text being pressed</Text>
        </View>
    </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Do you know of any way of achieving this?

Is it possible to somehow capture the touch start event from the parent while still allowing the event to propagate further in the chain? I was looking for anything allowing me to create a Synthetic event and emit it in React Native, but I was unable to find any solution.

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution to this problem?

Comment: @dchhetri It has been a long time since I posted this, I forgot the purpose of the code I was attempting... Anyway, I don't recall finding a solution at that time. Right now I can think of using PanResponder's onStartShouldSetPanResponder handler on the parent, spawning a Promise with the custom code, and immediately returning false from the handler (reject setting the PanResponder on the parent). Capture version of the handler should work as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function, which will be called when the parent is pressed, and call the same function when the child is pressed.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  onPress = () => {
    console.log('Parent Pressed');
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.onPress}>
          <View style={styles.button}>
            <Text>Parent</Text>
            <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => {
              console.log('Child Pressed')
              this.onPress()
            }} style={styles.child}>
              <Text>Child</Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>
          </View>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Checkout this stack example: https://snack.expo.io/@ashwith00/4ddff3

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, however, my question was about being able to do this, without adding the parent function to child's press event handler. The reason is that I have custom child components using custom PanResponder events, which are tricky to get working due to the way capturing start and move events works. Capturin and calling the parent press event during those PanResponder events interferes with the PanResponder handler's logic and breaks some functionality.